# Run another line code if a code processing time more than 30seconds

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm developing a new payment system for my website using Web Service.

```
...
$RESULT = DO_WEBSERVICE();
// If I dont get the result after 30 seconds, I want to cancel it using function
DO_CANCEL_WEBSERVICE();
```

How can I solve this problem? Should I use AJAX?

Comment: You are looking for timeout. If not, then count to 30 seconds and `die()`.

Comment: I see a part of an answer in comments.  Without an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the code that checks to see if you've gotten the response you want via a timer with a client-side **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)**.

In the example below, I'm using just a 5 second (5000 milliseconds) delay.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  // Do whatever test(s) you need to after the delay has expired
  // Here, I'm testing the textbox to see if it has any input
  if(document.querySelector("input").value === ""){
    alert("You haven't entered anything after 5 seconds!");
  } else {
    alert("Thanks for inputting some data.");
  }
}, 5000);
```

```html
<input>
```